# How can I install my custom-made theme on a wordpress.com blog?

Tags: theme-development, themes

I've only ever worked with WordPress on my own server. I'm using wordpress.com for my development environment, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to upload my themes since as far as I know I have no FTP access...

I'm sorry if this is something that should be obvious, but all I'm finding in searches is how to FTP themes into personal WP installs, which I already know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what Wordpress.com says:

> Because of the way WordPress.com’s technical infrastructure is
>   designed, we are not able to support uploading of custom WordPress
>   themes on our service.

You are only allowed to pick from pre-existing themes.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you need to know this difference: [WordPress.com and WordPress.org](http://en.support.wordpress.com/com-vs-org/)

**Excerpt**:

> WordPress.org (**self-hosted**) *Benefits*
>
> - Ability to upload custom themes
> - Ability to upload plugins
> - Complete control to change code if you’re technically minded

---

And also, from the `.com` documentation: [Uploading Custom Themes](http://en.support.wordpress.com/themes/adding-new-themes/)

**Excerpt**:

> Because of the way WordPress.com’s technical infrastructure is
>   designed, we are not able to support uploading of custom WordPress
>   themes on our service.
>
> However...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot install plugins on wordpress.com. You have to create a WordPress Site with the software offered on wordpress.org.

If you don't know how to install WordPress, I would recommend to choose a Managed WordPress Hosting like [MyWoHo](http://mywoho.com), [Wpengine](http://wpengine.com) or Websynthesis. MyWoHo starts at 3$/month. It's not much, if you wanto to try.